# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) on project tictactoe: Error assembling JAR

Tags: java, maven, javafx

EDIT: 2021-05-17

I've been struggling for a hours on a MAVEN project build that doesn't work.

It concerns a JaveFX project.
The project worked and ran fine before when I ran it in Intellij, using my local jfx library.

However, after I converted it to a maven project, it wouldn't compile anyone. Also, it won't compile into an executable JAR. The latter was kind of the point of the exercise.

Can anyone supply me with a MAVEN javafx project, with the correct POM etc, that will allow compilation into an executable JAR?

That way I can copy the essentials into my own project!

I would be very gratefull.

Comment: Is there more to the error (such as a stack trace)?

Comment: nothing! see my added pic.

Comment: See that tree on the left? Click on the root. Does that give more error information?

Comment: Sorry... you are correct... I added that info!

Comment: Interesting. The first error you describe is related to the `maven-jar-plugin`. But the stack trace is from the `exec-maven-plugin` failing. As for the second error, it looks like Maven is failing to configure JavaFX correctly. Since you're using JavaFX you may want to check out https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin

Comment: I think I made a mistake on my previous comment. Please my additions.